# My laptop Shuts down after suspend

Tags: suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer won’t wake from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147539/computer-wont-wake-from-suspend)

My Ubuntu shuts down after suspend. Does anyone has any idea?
Thanks a lot
Ubuntu 12.04,

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your system, such as version of Ubuntu, types of hardware,including graphics cards and drivers etc.? Please edit your question with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Install proprietary video drivers if available via hardware drivers applet. If that doesn't work disable C6 sleep state for CPU in BIOS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does not really work!